# How to make a class-instance accept parameters?

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, default

I wonder if there is a way to make a class instance that accepts parameters and generate results according to this parameter.

This is very common in VB.net built-in classes, but I wonder how to make it myself

```
Dim myNumbers as new NUMBERS
myNumbers.First = 1
myNumbers.Second = 2
Msgbox(myNumbers(1,2,3,4,5,5).max)
```

In the above code `myNumber` is a class which accepts some numbers and return the max.

Comment: Classes dont take parameters, methods do; and those look like Properties.  We cant see `NUMBERS` so we can only guess whats wrong

Comment: In your example, `First` and `Second` are properties of the class, and `Max` is a function. Read up on those aspects of classes.

Comment: Perhaps what you're talking about is class constructor having parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`Default` properties**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se6z814t.aspx) in order to achieve that. If you don't want it to be `Set`-able you can just mark it as [**`ReadOnly`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b2c2ka.aspx), and if you don't want to return a specific value just return `Nothing`.

**Returning something from the property:**

```
Default Public ReadOnly Property Calculate(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer, ByVal c As Integer) As Integer
    Get
        Dim d As Integer = a * b + c + Me.First
        DoSomeStuff(d)
        Return d * Me.Second
    End Get
End Property
```

**Returning nothing:**

```
Default Public ReadOnly Property Calculate(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As String) As Object
    Get
        Dim c As String = DoStuff()
        DoSomeOtherStuff(a, b, Me.First, Me.Second, c)
        Return Nothing
    End Get
End Property
```

**Usage example:**

```
'With return value.
Dim num As Integer = myNumbers(34, 5, 13)

'Ignoring return value.
Dim dummy As Object = myNumbers(64, "Hello World!")

'Ignoring return value.
Dim dummy As Object = myNumbers.Calculate(13, "I am text")
```

The only backside with this is that you must do something with the returned value (for instance assign it to a variable). Simply doing:

```
myNumbers(64, "Hello World!")
```

doesn't work.

Comment: @DragonInCresent : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!