# How do I write a VB class which allows indexing into/calling an instance?

Tags: vb.net, syntax

I'm honestly not sure what this is called, and if I did I'm sure I could google it in about 5 seconds.

I want to be able to write a class that I can sort of "index into" the way you do with a collection, eg:

```
Public Class FooClass
    Public Function magicKeyword(param as String) as String
        If param = "foo" Then
            Return "bar"
        Else
            Return "baz"
        End If
    End Function

    ...

End Class
```

And then use it like this:

```
Dim myObj as New FooClass
Dim output as String = myObj("foo") '<-- this is what I want to know how to do
' output = "bar"
```

What is this called, and what syntax would I use for the function?

---

Out of curiosity, can this also be done as a Shared function so the class itself can do it? e.g.:

```
Dim output as String = FooClass("foo")
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "bonus question".  The answer depends on what it does in the broader picture.  It partly sounds like a "string enum", partly a Collection Class or just a parameterized method as you have

Comment: By "bonus question" I mean that I'm curious about it, but I don't need to be able to do it right now, unlike my actual question which I do need.

Comment: As written the Function Me is a method of the class MyClass.  To get a response you would write `Dim output as String = myObj.Me("Foo")`

Comment: Using keywords like `MyClass` and `Me` as class and method names doesnt help clarify things.  As I said, the answer depends on *what* you are actually trying to achieve, as is it could be several things.  Is it really a collection you are indexing into?  Or is the result limited to a few things as in the post?

Comment: Are you talking about an indexer? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311323/how-to-create-an-indexer-property-in-visual-basic--net-or-in-visual-ba

Comment: @Plutonix Fixed keyword usage. I want to be able to use the same syntax as one would use to index into a List or get a value out of a Dictionary by passing in a key. While what I want to write won't be a collection itself, I do want it to behave like one. The implementation code is just a super-simple example.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I do believe so!

Comment: A `Default` property is what you want for the usage side; for the class side it looks more like the "string enum" trick.

Comment: Either @ZoharPeled or Plutonix, can you add an actual answer so I can mark it answered?

Comment: Duplicate: [How to make a class-instance accept parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650871/how-to-make-a-class-instance-accept-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is implementing a custom collection, and Microsoft provides [a pretty good guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306961/how-to-implement-custom-collections-in-visual-basic--net-or-in-visual) on how to accomplish this.

It should be said, however, that the collection classes already provided in .NET should be able to handle most use cases.  A truly custom collection is overkill in many instances.